# Kubernetes Clients API using Fabric8

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, fabric8

I'm using fabric8 java client library for Kubernetes. I am not able to find the best way to perform update operations on containers. Basically what I want to do is I have created a pod with container image as "nginx" now I want to update this image to "nginx:1.16.1".

What I have tried to do is

```
client.pods().inNamespace(podsModel.getNamespace()).withName(podsModel.getNamespace()).edit().editSpec()
                .editContainer(0).withNewImage("nginx:1.16.1").endContainer().endSpec().buildSpec();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit `Pod` spec using the code above, you just need to use `done()` rather than `buildSpec()`:

```
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
  Pod updatedPod = client.pods().inNamespace(namespace)
        .withName(podName)
        .edit().editSpec().editContainer(0)
        .withImage("nginx:1.16.1")
        .endContainer().endSpec().done();
}
```

However you should not be using `Pod` by itself. Pods are designed as relatively ephemeral, disposable entities. You should use some controller resource (`Deployment`, `StatefulSet` etc.) which can manage `Pod` objects on your behalf.

There is a document provided by the maintainers for common Fabric8 Kubernetes Client operations. You can take a look at this as well: [Fabric8 Kubernetes Client Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md).